# Unexpected error in windows service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I've got a WCF windows service running. It basically registers a number of clients and broadcasts messages to them as and when needed.
Generally it works fine, but recently I've been getting an error trying to register a new client, there are about 24 clients connected already, but when I try to register a 25th, I get "Index was outside the bounds of the array." being returned.
If I restart the service, all the clients reconnect, and the new client is able to register.
The NotifyServer method is called to broadcast a message to all the registered clients. This runs through the clients dictionary creating an async task that sends the message. This is done so that any issue happening with sending to one client does not impact the sending of the message to others.
The service is set up as to use a Reliable Connection.

```
    // List of connected Clients
    //
    private static Dictionary<string, IBroadcastorCallBack> clients = new Dictionary<string, IBroadcastorCallBack>();

    // lock indicator object 
    //
    private static object locker = new object();

    public string RegisterClient(string clientName)
    {
        string returnValue = "";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientName))
        {
            try
            {
                var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IBroadcastorCallBack>();
                lock (locker)
                {
                    // Remove the old client if its already there
                    //
                    if (clients.Keys.Contains(clientName))
                    {
                        clients.Remove(clientName);
                    }

                    // Add the new one
                    //
                    clients.Add(clientName, callback);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Return any error message
                //
                returnValue = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Notify the service of a message that can be broadcast
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventData">Message details</param>
    /// 
    public async void NotifyServer(EventDataType eventData)
    {

        DateTime Start = DateTime.Now;

        // Get a list copy of the dictionary  for all clients bar the one sending it. This is so we can't update the list inside the loop.
        //
        var clientlist = clients.Where(x => x.Key != eventData.ClientName).ToList();

        // Logging
        //
        if (MetricBroadcast.Properties.Settings.Default.LogXML)
        {
            log.Debug("XML Broadcast from " + eventData.ClientName + " to " + clientlist.Count.ToString() + " clients:\n" + eventData.EventMessage + "\n");
        }

        // Broadcast to all the valid clients
        //
        var BroadcastToClientList = clientlist.Select(client => BroadcastMessage(client.Value, client.Key, eventData)).ToList();

        // Wait until they are all done
        //
        await Task.WhenAll(BroadcastToClientList);

        // If we are logging and the broadcast time is > 1 second, we make a log entry
        //
        DateTime End = DateTime.Now;

        if (MetricBroadcast.Properties.Settings.Default.LogXML)
        {
            TimeSpan res = End - Start;

            if (res.TotalSeconds > 1)
            {
                var timetaken = string.Format("XML Broadcast Time : {0,2:00}:{1,2:00}.{2,3:000}", res.Minutes, res.Seconds, res.Milliseconds);

                log.Debug(timetaken);
            }
        }

    }

    private async Task<bool> BroadcastMessage(IBroadcastorCallBack clientCallback, string ClientKey, EventDataType eventData)
    {
        bool retval = true;

        Exception savedEx = null;

        DateTime BroadStart = DateTime.Now;

        try
        {
            // Send the message to the current client
            //
            clientCallback.BroadcastToClient(eventData);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // If we can't access the current clients callback method, 
            // we remove them from the clients list, as they've probably lost their connection.
            //
            clients.Remove(ClientKey);

            savedEx = e;

            retval = false;
        }

        // Log any broadcast that took > .5 seconds
        //
        DateTime BroadEnd = DateTime.Now;

        if (MetricBroadcast.Properties.Settings.Default.LogXML)
        {
            TimeSpan res = BroadEnd - BroadStart;

            if (res.TotalSeconds > .5)
            {
                var timetaken = string.Format("Single XML Broadcast Time to " + ClientKey + " : {0,2:00}:{1,2:00}.{2,3:000}", res.Minutes, res.Seconds, res.Milliseconds);

                log.Debug(timetaken, savedEx);
            }
        }

        return retval;
    }
```

Comment: You don't lock clients dictionary while reading (only when adding new client), so in multithreaded environment (like yours) - anything can happen.

Comment: ah! That will teach me to copy and paste old synchronous code as the basis of the async version... I'll take that out and give it a go.

Comment: OK, I've tried it and after waiting for a while (it only seems to happen after the service has been up for a while), the same problem occurred again.

Comment: Then update your question please with what exactly did you try.

Comment: I removed the locker object and the lock statement from RegisterClient code.

Comment: And I suggested the opposite option: add lock statement everywhere you access "clients" dictionary. Removing it from RegisterClient actually has exactly zero effect. Another option is to use ConcurrentDictionary instead of Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is incorrect usage of static `clients` `Dictionary` in multithreaded environment. New client can register at any time, including in the middle of your `BroadcastMessage` and `NotifyServer` functions. `Dictionary` was not designed for access from multiple threads. Take for example this:

```
clients.Where(x => x.Key != eventData.ClientName).ToList();
```

What happens if client is removed in the middle of this enumeration? Who knows, because it was not designed for this, but most likely some exception (like your "index out of bounds") will be thrown. That is why you need to lock your dictionary for both writes and reads, not just for writes:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, IBroadcastorCallback>> clientList;
lock (locker) 
    clientList = clients.Where(x => x.Key != eventData.ClientName).ToList();
```

Another option is to use `ConcurrentDictionary` class. It *was* designed for concurrent access and you can safely read and write to it from multiple threads.